# Run Terminal Commands on Raspberry Startup

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi3, startup, curses

I am working on a project in which I am using curses and pygame librarie, my python program/script can only be run through using terminal otherwise this error occurs

```
fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal
```

I want to run my program on startup of Raspberry pi by using these two commands

```
cd Desktop
python test.py
```

I am aware of rc.local but unable to run this....(first open terminal and then run these 2 commands in order to run my script)

Comment: Have you considered setting the Raspberry Pi to boot into terminal mode?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by setting Pi to boot in terminal mode

Comment: You can see here for more details on what I mean. https://www.kiwi-electronics.nl/blog?journal_blog_post_id=5&lang=en

Comment: got it how to open the terminal on startup, but how to run these two commands that I want to run in my case (1. cd Desktop    2.python test.py) ??

Answer (score 0):

Running on startup, e.g., using **`rc.local`**, there's at least two problems:

- the **`TERM`** environment variable is not set (giving the `setupterm: could not find terminal` message)
- you won't be able to handle input, only output...

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: tutorials are off-topic, but [`fdopen`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-fdopen/) and `dup2` are the usual methods.

Answer (score 0):

I spent around 1 day and test 4 solutions for Linux/raspberry startup run script issues. Then here is the solution (I choose crontab)

1. open crontab (use linux@crontab -e -> not use sudo crontab -e ... thats could be error in future some access for script etc.)

pi@ crontab -e

Then choose nano and edit like this... It is tricky, ı found after test may be more than 10x times:

```
@reboot cd /home/pi/beetool && /usr/bin/python3 run.py &
```

My code is waiting for me under /home/pi/beetool. If you don't change the directory that occurs error.

And my code uses infinite loop so I have to finish with "&" as you see above.

So I hope that helps someone, too ...