# how to run a Python3 script at startup on Raspberry PI all the time, with linked influxdb database

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, startup, debian-buster

I have a python3 script running on a Raspberry Pi on Debian 10 Buster, I can run in a terminal window but not on start up?

I am using the following line of code at the end of the file in /etc/profile

`nohup python3 statlogger.py -db=stat_logger_db -sn=test`

whilst the line of code works in the terminal window when I run it manually it will not work on starting the pi

I have also tried

`nohup python3 statlogger.py & -db=stat_logger_db -sn=test`

The python code needs to run at startup and then continuously whilst the pi is powered on, any thought

Comment: `/etc/profile` is the wrong place to start stuff. Startup stuff should be in `/etc/rc.local` or under `systemctl` https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units  Also, beware of paths to files in such scripts - they are not run in, or looking in your login directory.

Comment: I added `nohup python3 statlogger.py -db=stat_logger_db -sn=test` to `sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

Answer (score 2):

I spent around 1 day and test 4 solutions for Linux/raspberry startup run script issues. Then here is the solution (I choose crontab)

1. open crontab (use linux@crontab -e -> not use sudo crontab -e ... thats could be error in future some access for script etc.)

pi@ crontab -e

Then choose nano and edit like this... It is tricky, ı found after test may be more than 10x times:

```
@reboot cd /home/pi/beetool && /usr/bin/python3 run.py &
```

My code is waiting for me under /home/pi/beetool. If you don't change the directory that occurs error.

And my code uses infinite loop so I have to finish with "&" as you see above.

So I hope that helps someone, too ...

I aslo shared in: [Run Terminal Commands on Raspberry Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647466/run-terminal-commands-on-raspberry-startup/64221852#64221852)

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found to run a program on Raspberry Pi at startup is to use the systemd files.

1. Create A Unit File

Open a new sample unit file using the following command:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/sample.service
```

2. Add the following text to the new file.(Remember to change the
   python file path to your file):

```
[Unit]
Description=My Sample Service
After=multi-user.target
    
[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/sample.py
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save and exit using "CTRL+E" then when asked to save "Y" and "Enter"

3. Set the permission of the file to 644 :

```
sudo chmod 644 /lib/systemd/system/sample.service
```

4. tell systemd to start it during the boot sequence using:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable sample.service
```

5. Reboot the Pi using

```
sudo reboot now
```

source:
https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/#systemd